# Helm upgrade check if values file exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have a helm deploy template with helm upgrade command which by default uses `<environment>-values.yaml` as values file. We have those files for regular environments like dev, prod or int, but sometimes we have to configure some custom environment, where we do not want to set any values file, but rather use default `values.yaml`.

Is there any way to check if file exists in yaml? If `<environment>-values.yaml` exists then it should be used in helm upgrade, but when it does not, then `values.yaml` should be used instead.

Right now we get `no such file or directory` when env values file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine your only reasonable way of doing this - is wrapping helm with a script that would check if the file exists

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script wrapper to include the option only if it exists.  (This approach in particular inspired by [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), but the `${variable+value}` syntax is part of POSIX shell syntax, so not bash-specific.)

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Do environment-specific values exist?
env_values="$ENVIRONMENT-values.yaml"
if [ -f "$env_values" ]; then
  have_env_values=true
fi

# Launch Helm, passing `-f` if the file exists, and passing any
# additional arguments to this script on to Helm.
helm ${have_env_values+-f "$env_values"} "$@"
```

```bash
ENVIRONMENT=production ./run-helm template .
```

Also remember that a chart's `values.yaml` is always used, but settings from `helm -f` files override it.  So for this case it's enough to just not pass a `-f` option if the per-environment values file doesn't exist.